# new page shows values entered in previous record

Tags: java, jsp

I have a page which takes user details. Once I save them for one user and trying to create another user, two fields of new page showing the values entered for previous user, I can edit them. What I want is, when I select the new page it should come with blank fields or some default values that I mentioned. This issue is happening in the same session. When I try to do the same with different sessions, it is working fine. My observation was that, those previously entered values are coming from form object(front end). How can I resolve this? Where might be the changes in jsp/handler?

Comment: What browser are you observing this behavior in? Some browsers remember the values in fields and displays them again when the same page is rendered.

Comment: You might want to *clear* the *browser history*.

Comment: if it is cashe issue. what might be the reason to happen this only for few fields. and this is happening only in  one of many pages. it is working fine for other pages . my browser is IE